# php: issue on how to check the static method?

Tags: php

```
$this->categories = tx_dagoupost_lib::getCategories();
```

For above code: how could I find out wheather `getCategories()` declared as staticor not? Because we can also call normal function this way: `tx_dagoupost_lib::getCategories();`, although it is not proper. It seems that I can use this one: `ReflectionMethod::isStatic`, but I do not know how to use it, there is no example here: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isstatic.php, so can anyone show me how to check if `getCategories()` is static function.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the program? Why don't you just look at the code and see if it say "static" before writing the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the rest of the `Reflection` documentation, you'll see that this is how you get a `ReflectionMethod` object:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('tx_dagoupost_lib');
$method = $class->getMethod('getCategories');
if ($method->isStatic()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
$check_static = new ReflectionMethod('tx_dagoupost_lib', 'getCategories');

if( $check_static->isStatic() ) {
   echo "Its static method";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC | ReflectionMethod::IS_FINAL);
var_dump($methods);
```

[view more details ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php)